# Create Column as below

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in Excel

```
col1    col2
NA      Missing
12      Pass
NA      Missing
```

So, I need to generate col3, as if Missing then mention Missing
else take value "12".
just like below:

```
col3
Missing
12
Missing
```

How to do this in VBA?
Note: i need to get format even, not only the value
I have tried to stored all the values in array and then display in excel but it doesn't worked and even i need format

```
Set cw = Worksheets("5").Range("G15:G17")
For Each cwVal In cw
If cwVal = "Missing" Then
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
    arr(i) = cwVal
    i = i + 1
Else
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
    arr(i) = cwVal
    i = i + 1
End If
Next cwVal
Worksheets("Summary").Range("G6:G8") = arr()
```

Comment: The real question is "What have you tried so far?"  Note that StackOverflow is a collaborative site for helping with *specific* coding issues, not a code for you service.  If you need help generating initial code, please try the Macro Recorder in the Developer tab of Excel.  Regarding your specific question, there are numerous ways to do this, though that would make this question **too broad**, which may result in this question being flagged for closure.  Note that this does not require VBA to pull the values, e.g., =if(b3="missing",b3,a3), and regarding formatting, that could mean many things

Comment: Hi, i know the formula but i need this in vba because i have just asked sample but a huge data is there; Moreover this formula can't copy the format of that cell, i need even format

Comment: Huge data shouldn't matter - Excel's quite good at that and it's only a simple formula that @Cyril suggests.  The format shouldn't matter either if you've only get text or numbers - text will copy across as text, numbers as numbers.  Dates on the other hand would come over as their numerical equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just give you a loop with a select case, so you can tell what to copy (keeps format) and simply pastes the copied cell:

```
dim i as long, lr as long
with sheets("5") 'assuming this is maintained
    lr = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'dynamically finds last row in sheet
    for i = 2 to lr 'assumes row 1 is headers
        select case .cells(i,2).value
            case "missing"
                .cells(i,2).copy
            case else
                .cells(i,1).copy
        end select
        .cells(i,3).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevaluesandnumberformats
    next i
end with
```

wrote this from my head, not tested

---

**edit1:**  went back and used .pastespecial with keeping soruce formatting... forgot about that when i originally wrong .paste

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5")

        j = 6

        For i = 15 To 17

            If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Missing" Then
                .Range("G" & j).Value = "Missing"
            Else
                .Range("G" & j).Value = .Range("F" & i).Value
            End If

            j = j + 1

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```